# Problem with getting filename before upload in uppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, uppy

I am trying to get the uploaded filename before it's actually uploaded. So i tried to use `onBeforeUpload` event and log it to console but nothing returns.

Below is the code I have used. What did I do wrong?

Thank you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Uppy</title>
    <link href="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v1.28.1/uppy.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="drag-drop-area"></div>

    <script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v1.28.1/uppy.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const uppy = Uppy.Core({
          debug: true,
          autoProceed: true,
          restrictions: {
              maxFileSize: 2147483647,
              maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
              minNumberOfFiles: 1,
              allowedFileTypes: ['.pdf', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif']
          }
      })
        .use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
          inline: true,
          target: '#drag-drop-area'
        })
        .use(Uppy.Tus, {endpoint: 'https://tusd.tusdemo.net/files/'})

        onBeforeUpload: (files) => {
          console.log("this is event before upload");
        }

      uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
        console.log('Upload complete! We’ve uploaded these files:', result.successful)
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`onBeforeUpload` is a argument and hence should be supplied while initiating `Uppy.Core{}` object.
You are trying to supply an argument after the `Uppy.Core` object has already been initiated.

This is currently working.

```
 const uppy = Uppy.Core({
          debug: true,
          autoProceed: true,
          restrictions: {
              maxFileSize: 2147483647,
              maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
              minNumberOfFiles: 1,
              allowedFileTypes: ['.pdf', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.txt']
          },
          onBeforeUpload: (files) => {
          console.log("this is event before upload");
        }
      })
        .use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
          inline: true,
          target: '#drag-drop-area'
        })
        .use(Uppy.Tus, {endpoint: 'https://tusd.tusdemo.net/files/'})

        

      uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
        console.log('Upload complete! We’ve uploaded these files:', result.successful)
      })
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/du3vwyak/

Answer (score 0):

You would like to get file for what? Display before upload? Change name? or what?

Did you try put `onBeforeUpload` inside `const uppy = Uppy.Core({...})`?
Based on your code i will put it there.

Additionally as you can read [here](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#onBeforeFileAdded-currentFile-files-gt-currentFile) `onBeforeFileAdded` is for one file and [here](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#onBeforeUpload-files-gt-files) `onBeforeUpload` is for all files.

If you would like to display files before it is uploaded you can use [file-added](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#file-added) or [files-added](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#files-added) event.

Example:

```
const myUppy = new Uppy.Core({...}) //initialize Uppy with your parameters

myUppy.on('file-added', (file) => {
   document.querySelector('.file-list').innerHTML = file.name //or whatever
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will loop over all the files saved in the uppy instance store and log their names. Of course you can use onBeforeUpload to do any operation on the files like adding meta data etc.

```
uppy.onBeforeUpload: (files) => {
        files.forEach((file)=> console.log(file.name));
        return "done";
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.